# Filter an array of ISO date by days of the week in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime, angular-moment

I have an array of ISO dates I'm trying to sort and get only the next seven days from it

Here is the sample

```js
Here is the sample code

daysdata = [{time: '2022-01-23T11:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-23T12:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-24T11:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-24T12:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-24T17:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-24T23:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T00:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T04:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T05:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T06:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-25T07:00:00Z', data: {…}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T14:00:00Z', data: {…}},        
     {time: '2022-01-25T15:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-26T13:00:00Z', data: {…}},
     {time: '2022-01-26T14:00:00Z', data: {…}},
     {time: '2022-01-26T15:00:00Z', data: {…}},
     {time: '2022-01-27T13:00:00Z', data: {…}},
     {time: '2022-01-27T14:00:00Z', data: {…}},
     {time: '2022-01-27T15:00:00Z', data: {…}},
     {time: '2022-01-28T14:00:00Z', data: {…}},     
     {time: '2022-01-28T15:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-28T16:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-29T18:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-29T19:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-30T08:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-30T09:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-30T10:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
     {time: '2022-01-30T11:00:00Z', data: {…}},    
    ]
```

That is the sample code.

Comment: where is you sample code? what goes wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the next seven days from today(the current day)?

Comment: convert your date to epoch using `.getTime()` and then you can compare with your required date, using array filter

Comment: @seb_dom Yes I want to get only next seven days from today, and as you can see there are several date time in a day.

Comment: @NinaScholz the problem is there are several time in a day in the array, first I need to filter by date the next seven days from the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm is:

1. Sort the data by the value of the time property
2. Find the index of the first day on the same date as the start date
3. If an element is found, push that element into an array
4. Increment the search date by 1 day

A lexical sort is used to sort on *time* and to find the records to return as it's an ISO 8601 string. Conversion to Date objects will work too but that seems unnecessary.

To select each date, *dStart* is set to the start of the UTC day and *dEnd* is set to the end of the UTC day. If no date is found in that range, none is added to the array. This prevents the case of a multi day gap in the data producing multiple entries of the same object (i.e. the first one after the gap) in the *selected* array.

If this should be based on local dates, then use *setHours* instead of *setUTCHours*.

```js
/* Given data as an array of objects, return
 * first on date plus first on next n days
 * Dates are UTC, not local
 */
function getFirstNDays(data, n = 1, date = new Date()) {

  // Make sure n is a positive integer
  if (n % 1 || n < 0) return;

  data.sort((a, b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time)); 

  let dStart = new Date(date);
  dStart.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);

  let dEnd = new Date(dStart);
  dEnd.setUTCHours(23,59,59,999);
  let selected = [];
  
  while (n--) {
    let index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.time >= dStart.toISOString() && obj.time <= dEnd.toISOString());

    // If record found, add to selected array
    if (index != -1) {
      selected.push(data[index]);
    }

    dStart.setUTCDate(dStart.getUTCDate() + 1);
    dEnd.setUTCDate(dEnd.getUTCDate() + 1);
  }

  // Return selected values
  return selected;
}

let daysdata = [
  {time: '2022-01-20T11:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-23T11:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-23T12:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-24T11:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-24T12:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-24T17:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-24T23:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-25T00:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-25T04:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-25T05:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-25T06:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-25T07:00:00Z', data: {}},   
  {time: '2022-01-25T14:00:00Z', data: {}},        
  {time: '2022-01-25T15:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-26T13:00:00Z', data: {}},
  {time: '2022-01-26T14:00:00Z', data: {}},
  {time: '2022-01-26T15:00:00Z', data: {}},
  {time: '2022-01-27T13:00:00Z', data: {}},
  {time: '2022-01-27T14:00:00Z', data: {}},
  {time: '2022-01-27T15:00:00Z', data: {}},
  {time: '2022-01-28T14:00:00Z', data: {}},     
  {time: '2022-01-28T15:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-28T16:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-29T18:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-29T19:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-30T08:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-30T09:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-30T10:00:00Z', data: {}},    
  {time: '2022-01-30T11:00:00Z', data: {}},    
];

console.log(getFirstNDays(daysdata, 7, new Date(Date.UTC(2022,0,23))));
```

Updated to suit updated requirements.

Comment: thanks but maybe my question wasn't properly asked from the above answer it sorts the first seven datetime but what I need is to sort and pick only the first index in the array of same date.
Like sort for only 2022-01-23T11:00:00Z , the next new date which is 2022-01-24T11:00:00Z and so on ...

Comment: @Ojhey—the above sorts the entire array, not just the first seven elements. There is enough information in the answer to write something that fits your updated criteria. E.g. get *startIndex*, increment the date by a day, get the next *startIndex*, and so on.

Comment: -thanks you’re a lifesaver!!!… exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

just sort by Array.sort and pick the first n elements of an array by Array.slice

```js
 

daysdata = [{time: '2022-01-23T11:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-23T12:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-24T11:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-24T12:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-24T17:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-24T23:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T00:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T04:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T05:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T06:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-25T07:00:00Z', data: {}},   
     {time: '2022-01-25T14:00:00Z', data: {}},        
     {time: '2022-01-25T15:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-26T13:00:00Z', data: {}},
     {time: '2022-01-26T14:00:00Z', data: {}},
     {time: '2022-01-26T15:00:00Z', data: {}},
     {time: '2022-01-27T13:00:00Z', data: {}},
     {time: '2022-01-27T14:00:00Z', data: {}},
     {time: '2022-01-27T15:00:00Z', data: {}},
     {time: '2022-01-28T14:00:00Z', data: {}},     
     {time: '2022-01-28T15:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-28T16:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-29T18:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-29T19:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-30T08:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-30T09:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-30T10:00:00Z', data: {}},    
     {time: '2022-01-30T11:00:00Z', data: {}},    
    ];

   sortData = daysdata.sort((a,b) => (a.time < b.time) ? 1 : ((b.time < a.time) ? -1 : 0));

   console.log(sortData.slice(0,7));
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not sorting just by first seven element of the array because there are several date time in a day  in the array.